# Hiding NS significance and brackets in R, using geom_pwc, stat_pvalue_manual, or stat_compare_means

Tags: r, ggplot2, p-value, ggpubr, rstatix

I am facing issues with `stat_compare_means`, `geom_pwc`, and `stat_pvalue_manual`. The issues are as follows:

1. `stat_compare_means` actually works decently for the most part, except for the fact that I cannot seem to get rid of the brackets of NS significance. `hide.ns` only gets rid of the label itself but not the brackets, and I cannot seem to get those brackets to not appear.
2. With both `geom_pwc` and `stat_pvalue_manual`, I read that `hide.ns` also hides brackets. However, when I use either of these functions with `hide.ns=TRUE`, all of my significances are removed (despite not all of them being ns).

My data is a df with three relevant variables: willingness (y-axis), gender (x-axis), and risk (facet). My plot is a boxplot. There are three facets (risk: 0.1%, 2%, and 10%), four gender categories (men, women, non-binary, and general), and willingness is a continuous 0-100 scale. The "general" gender is just the combined data of the other three gender categories, to observe the general trend non-gender-specific, and should be left out of the statistical comparisons.

My code is as follows:

```r
ggboxplot(combined_data,x = "gender", y = "willingness", color = "black", fill="gender", palette = c("coral4","#BBD1EA","#FFBB99","#FFF6BD"), facet.by = "Risk", short.panel.labs = FALSE, outlier.shape = NA) +
geom_point(aes(x=gender,y=willingness,fill=gender),position=position_jitterdodge(),alpha=0.3,size=1,shape=20) + 
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust=1)) + 
theme(legend.position="none", axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),axis.title.x = element_blank()) + 
stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons, label="p.signif", hide.ns = TRUE)
```

Where, in `stat_compare_means`, "my_comparisons" is:

```r
my_comparisons <- list(c("Men", "Women"), c("Men", "Non-binary"), c("Women", "Non-binary"))
```

This produces the first image attached below.

[image: using stat_compare_means]

When I try to use `geom_pwc` or `stat_pvalue_manual`, they both produce the same figure. Note: this one does not seem to allow me to specify the comparisons, so "general" is included here. If anyone knows how to specify comparisons, that would be great. The code is:

```r
ggboxplot(combined_data,x = "gender", y = "willingness", color = "black", fill="gender", palette = c("coral4","#BBD1EA","#FFBB99","#FFF6BD"), facet.by = "Risk", short.panel.labs = FALSE, outlier.shape = NA) + 
geom_point(aes(x=gender,y=willingness,fill=gender),position=position_jitterdodge(),alpha=0.3,size=1,shape=20) + 
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust=1)) + 
theme(legend.position="none", axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),axis.title.x = element_blank()) + 
geom_pwc(group.by="x.var",label="p.signif",hide.ns=TRUE)
```

And the figure is found below.

[image: using geom_pwc, hide.ns=true]

And this is what it looks like with `hide.ns=false`, noting the present significance levels:

[image: hide.ns=false]

Using `stat_pvalue_manual` produces the same result as `geom_pwc`, noting the following code:

```r
stat.test <- compare_means(willingness ~ gender, data = combined_data, 
              group.by = "Risk")
ggboxplot(.......same as above) + 
stat_pvalue_manual(stat.test, label = "p.signif", hide.ns = TRUE)
```

So if anyone can help with either:

1. Removing ns brackets with stat_compare_means, or
2. Specifying comparisons and fixing the `hide.ns` issue with `geom_pwc` or `stat_pvalue_manual`

I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Saud! Welcome to StackOverflow. If you could make your example reproducible, that would be great! See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I didn't know that `ggpubr::ggboxplot` existed but I have done a grouped box plot using `ggplot::geom_boxplot` that I think would fit your specifications. Let me know if you're interested in seeing a code example and I'll post an answer in the next day or so.

Answer (score 0):

You can just automatically compute p-values before ploting and based on that decide on the comparisons. In my case stat_compare_means usus wilcoxin so I use seurat findMarkers which is quick and also has wilcoxin. Like in my example:

```
comparisonsi <- list(c("AL", "DR"), c("AL", "SR100"))

pval_AL_vs_DR <- FindMarkers(sne_subset, ident.1 = "AL", ident.2 = "DR", features = c(gene), min.pct = 0, logfc.threshold = 0)[gene, "p_val"]
pval_AL_vs_SR100 <- FindMarkers(sne_subset, ident.1 = "AL", ident.2 = "SR100", features = c(gene), min.pct = 0, logfc.threshold = 0)[gene, "p_val"]

if (pval_AL_vs_DR<=0.05 & pval_AL_vs_SR100<=0.05) {comparisonsi <- list(c("AL", "DR"), c("AL", "SR100"))}
if (pval_AL_vs_DR<=0.05 & pval_AL_vs_SR100>0.05) {comparisonsi <- list(c("AL", "DR"))}
if (pval_AL_vs_DR>0.05 & pval_AL_vs_SR100<=0.05) {comparisonsi <- list(c("AL", "SR100"))}
if (pval_AL_vs_DR>0.05 & pval_AL_vs_SR100>0.05) {comparisonsi <- list()}
    
    
p_violin <- VlnPlot(sne_subset, features = gene, group.by = "diet", pt.size = 0, log = T) + 
stat_compare_means(comparisons = comparisonsi, method = "wilcox.test", label = "p.signif", hide.ns = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody else comes across this problem: I had a similar problem where I compared values in a large amount of samples across about 50 different groups and subgroups from about 30 clinical parameters and wanted to auto-generate plots to spot significant changes. Doing this by hand is not feasible and checking all possible combinations across e.g. 7 groups generates so many brackets that you can hardly see the plot afterwards.

In order to generate plots **only containing comparisons between groups which significantly differ from each other**, I created a little function that you can use as-is with stats_compare_means. (For anybody less experienced in R, just execute this code in order to use this function)

```
significant_comparisons <- function(values,group.vector,adjust.method,paired){
  if(missing(paired)){paired=F}
  #toss all groups with n<2
  groups_n_greater_1 = names(table(group.vector)[table(group.vector)>1])
  values=values[group.vector %in% groups_n_greater_1]
  group.vector=group.vector[group.vector %in% groups_n_greater_1]
  
  #pairwise t-Test
  test=pairwise.t.test(values, group.vector,p.adjust.method = adjust.method, paired = paired)
  #Generate list with significant comparisons
  p.list=list()
  for(i in 1:nrow(test$p.value)){
    for(k in 1:ncol(test$p.value)){
      if(is.na(test$p.value[i,k])==F){
        if(test$p.value[i,k]<=0.05){p.list=c(p.list,list(c(rownames(test$p.value)[i],colnames(test$p.value)[k])))}
      }
    }
  }
  return(p.list)
}
```

It uses, in this case, a pairwise t-Test to determine if there is a significant difference between two groups and makes a list out of these comparisons. You can of course change from pairwise.t.test to pairwise.wilcox.test or whatever suits your needs.

You can embed this function into stats_compare_means like so (following your example):

```
ggboxplot(combined_data,x = "gender", y = "willingness", color = "black", fill="gender", palette = c("coral4","#BBD1EA","#FFBB99","#FFF6BD"), facet.by = "Risk", short.panel.labs = FALSE, outlier.shape = NA) +
geom_point(aes(x=gender,y=willingness,fill=gender),position=position_jitterdodge(),alpha=0.3,size=1,shape=20) + 
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust=1)) + 
theme(legend.position="none", axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),axis.title.x = element_blank()) + 
stat_compare_means(comparisons = significant_comparisons(combined_data$willingness,combined_data$gender,adjust.method="bonferroni",paired=F), label="p.signif", hide.ns = TRUE)
```

I hope this helps!